# how to auto Expand Dropdownlist in Ie8

Tags: asp.net, html, css, internet-explorer

asp:dropdownlist with fixed width cannot automatically  expand the option according to the length of the content in Ie8

Comment: do not mention width property. it will expand then

Comment: design will be broken with out width property for dropdown .

Comment: You would have to give the width in percentage only then it will expand.

Answer (score 0):

Try using min-width property instead of width.  That way if it needs to expand, it can.
Example:

```
select {
    min-width:300px;
}
```